# Prove $(y^2-zx)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(x^2-yz)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+(z^2-xy)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$, $u=f(x^2+2yz,y^2+2zx)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $u=f(x^2+2yz,y^2+2zx)$, prove that
$$ (y^2-zx) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + (x^2-yz)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+(z^2-xy)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0
$$

I am trying to prove the above but I am stuck. Could anyone help?

Comment: If we write $X = x^2 + 2yz$ and $Y = y^2 + 2zx$, then we have $u = f (X,Y)$. Thus, $\partial_x u = \partial_x X \partial_X f + \partial_x Y \partial_Y f$, and so on.

Comment: The chain rule will be the key here.